# Basic Java Scanning

Tags: java, string, parsing

So, I'm trying to be able to take in user input and add up each number in the string and print it out as well as calculating the product. I figured out how to take in each digit but i'm having trouble with numbers of variable length. this is what it prints currently :

```
Please enter '.' when you want to terminate
1 2 3
Numbers: 1 2 3
Sum: 13  Product: 12
```

This is the method that calculates user input after scanning

```
public void set(String userInput)// method set returns void
{
    num=0;// reset each variable so new input can be passed
    sum=0;
    product=1;
    String empty="";

    for(int index=0; index<userInput.length(); index++)// goes through each character in string
    {

        if(Character.isDigit(userInput.charAt(index))==true)// checks if character in the string is a digit
        { 
            empty+=userInput.charAt(index);
        }
        else
        {
            //if it is then parse that character into an integer and assign it to num
            num=Integer.parseInt(empty);

            // adds each digit to sum
            sum+=num;
            product*=num;
            // multiplies each digit by product and stores in "product"
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Maybe
    && Character.isDigit(userInput.charAt(index + 1))
Btw you don't need the == true check :P
Then if its not a digit add it as a space and when it comes to parsing split it around " " and parse them all then add etc
If it is a digit use a while loop to loop until it isn't a digit and while its a digit add it to empty. also when the while is done add a space so the next iteration adds a new number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to clear out **empty** after using it and also make sure to continue to process after the last digit. You're getting 1 + 12 and 1 * 12 and missing the 3.

Comment: thanks! that worked but i'm not sure why it'd not taking in the last digit hmmm

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you, separate the number with spaces since the beginning:

the user input is: 1 2 3 10 20

and then you can get an Array

```
String[] numbers = userInput.trim().split(" ");
```

and you have to adapt you code.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion that'd be great in any other situation but for this i'm not allowed to use those as it makes the assignment too trivial